# Inheritence in JSP/Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, extends

In Java we can have something like the following;

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    // something..
}
```

How about a JSP or a servlet, can they extend another JSP or servlet?
Please justify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your own implementation of Servlet class or HttpServlet class

About JSPs you can create a tag and import it in you jsp as an "extend" you jsp will just be a implementation of that template ( tag )